# Read All Value From Cache

Tags: c#, caching, .net-core

i am using .netcore with Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed , i have a scenario to get all the keys and also i need to flush all the values.
I have searched many articles no one gives the exact idea to get all values or Flush values. IDistributedCache don't have flush the redis cache.
Can anyone help on this.

Comment: As `IDistributedCache` doesn't offer a way to do these things, you will have to go around the interface and communicate directly with the implementation to achieve what you want. What are you using for your distributed cache?

Comment: Hi Paul , I am using the Redis Cache for distributed  cache

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad for me to provide a complete answer right now. To get you started, you need to know about the `SCAN` command in Redis (https://redis.io/commands/scan) and connecting to your instance using a client such as the StackExchange Redis client (https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/)

Answer (score 0):

For my project ,the follow function return all matched keys:

```cs
//using StackExchange.Redis;
/// <summary>
/// 搜索所有与<see cref="keyStr"/>相匹配的缓存的key
/// </summary>
/// <param name="keyStr">搜索词,*表示任意字符</param>
/// <param name="dbIndex">redis中查找db</param>
/// <param name="trimRedisInstanceName">是否在查询前及返回前去除<see cref="Extension.RedisInstanceName"/>前缀</param>
/// <returns>redis中的key列表,<see cref="trimRedisInstanceName"/>参数设置是否包括<see cref="Extension.RedisInstanceName"/></returns>
protected async Task<List<string>> FilterByKey(string keyStr, int dbIndex = 0, bool trimRedisInstanceName = true)
{
    //创建连接
    var conn = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(_configuration.GetSection("Cache")["Redis"]);

    //获取db
    var db = conn.GetDatabase(dbIndex);
    var listResult = new List<string>();

    //遍历集群内服务器
    foreach (var endPoint in conn.GetEndPoints())
    {
        //获取指定服务器
        var server = conn.GetServer(endPoint);
        //在指定服务器上使用 keys 或者 scan 命令来遍历key

        foreach (var key in server.Keys(dbIndex, Extension.RedisInstanceName + keyStr))
        {
            if (trimRedisInstanceName)
            {
                listResult.Add(key.ToString().Replace(Extension.RedisInstanceName, ""));
            }
            else
            {
                listResult.Add(key);
            }
            //获取key对于的值
            //var val = db.StringGet(key);
            Console.WriteLine($"key: {key}, value:");
        }
    }
    return listResult;
}
```

In the method,`Extension.RedisInstanceName` used in

```cs
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
            {
                options.Configuration = config.GetSection("Cache")["Redis"];
                options.InstanceName = RedisInstanceName;
            });
```

it used by this:

```cs
//刷新缓存
var allCacheCompany = await FilterByKey("xxxx.*");
foreach (var companyKey in allCacheCompany)
{
   await _cache.RemoveAsync(companyKey);
}
```